# If $g^2 = e$ for all $g \in G$, then $G$ is abelian

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a group. Prove that $g^2 = e$ for all $g \in G$, then $G$ is abelian. ($e$ is the identity element.)

My Solution: Let $a,b \in G$. Then $a(ab)b = a^2b^2 = e^2 =e$. Now I tried to reverse $ab$ in the brackets to get the same solution to show that the group is also commutative but I was not able to do so.

Comment: Use also $(ab)^2=e$, with $(ab)^2=abab$.

Comment: Please make titles informative!!

Comment: How is $(ab)^2 = e$

Comment: This is one of the most duplicated group questions I know of. @Ron.J.Adams Please use the search function. I'm 100% certain you'd have found an answer before you posted your question.

Comment: What @rschwieb said. And almost everytime an answer with cancellation is given instead of the more aesthetic $ab = a(abab)b=(aa)ba(bb)=ba$.

Answer (score 8):

Let $a,b \in G$ be arbitrary elements. Notice:

$$abab = (ab)^2 = e = a^2 b^2 = aabb$$

Cancellation gives $ba = ab$.

Comment: What I don't get is how $(ab)^2 = e$.

Comment: Because $ab$ is in the group since $a,b$ are in the group. And the property $g^2 = e$ holds foe very element of $g$. In particular, it must hold for $g = ab$

Comment: I didn't know that you could do this. So like shouldn't G have the multiplicative property for this.

Comment: $$a,b \in G \implies ab \in G$$

Comment: @Ron.J.Adams what is this "multiplicative property"? Does a group not satisfy it by definition?

Answer (score 1):

we have  that $ab ab= e$.  Thus (multiply by $b$ two sides)  $abab^2=b$  or $aba=b$. In  the same  way $aba^2=ba$  or $ab=ba.$